# Beautifulsoup JSON Remove text

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

Can anyone explain how I scrape this data with beautifulsoup? Because of the ''Description'' tag, I can't find the elements.

I want to delete the text from Description till start of the brand element.

Using PYTHON.

Thanks!

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "",
    "description": "&lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;style&gt;
    .infobox {
    padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
    background-color: #fffb98;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
&lt;/style&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;
    &lt;h2&gt;PlayStation 5&lt;/h2&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;infobox&quot;&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Informatie over pre-orders&lt;/h3&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Het is niet mogelijk om via onze webshop een pre-order te plaatsen.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Heb jij reeds een pre-order geplaatst op de PlayStation 5? Dan neemt de winkel waar jij dit deed &lt;strong&gt;vanaf 17 september zo spoedig mogelijk telefonisch contact met je op&lt;/strong&gt; om de status van je pre-order te bespreken. Wij nemen in &lt;strong&gt;chronologische volgorde&lt;/strong&gt; contact op met al onze PS5 pre-order klanten geplaatst tot en met 16 september 2020. Naargelang de datum waarop jij je pre-order plaatste kan het &lt;strong&gt;tot 10 dagen&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;nbsp;duren alvorens je winkel telefonisch contact met je opneemt.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Had jij v&amp;oacute;&amp;oacute;r 17 september 2020 nog geen pre-order geplaatst op de PlayStation 5? Ga dan langs in jouw Game Mania store om een pre-order te plaatsen en kom chronologisch op de PS5 wachtlijst te staan. Bij het plaatsen van een nieuwe pre-order is een aanbetaling van € 50 verplicht.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Welkom in een nieuwe wereld van realistisch gamen&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Ontdek een diepere game-ervaring op PS5&amp;trade; met ondersteuning voor haptische feedback, adaptieve triggers en 3D-audiotechnologie.&lt;br&gt;
    &lt;br&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;Voel meer met haptische feedback&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Geniet van haptische feedback via de draadloze DualSense&amp;trade;-controller in geselecteerde PS5-games en ervaar de effecten en impact van je acties in de game met je zintuigen.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Voel de weerstand met adaptieve triggers&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Maak gebruik van meeslepende adaptieve triggers met dynamische weerstandsniveaus die de fysieke impact van in-game activiteiten in geselecteerde PS5-games simuleren.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Kijk met geluid dankzij 3D-audio&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Duik in muzikale panorama&#39;s waar het voelt alsof het geluid uit elke richting komt. Met Tempest 3D AudioTech in ondersteunde games komt je omgeving echt tot leven via je hoofdtelefoon of de luidsprekers van je tv.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "Game Mania"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4",
        "ratingCount": "5187"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "499",
        "availability" : "OutOfStock"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you do not need `beautifulsoup` for that load your scraped `string` with `json.loads()` and access it as `dictionary`.

Try to replace the `\n` that is something `json.loads()` could not handle:

```
json.loads(string.replace('\n',''))
```

**Example**

```
import json

string = '''{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "",
    "description": "&lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;style&gt; .infobox {
    padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
    background-color: #fffb98;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
&lt;/style&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;
    &lt;h2&gt;PlayStation 5&lt;/h2&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;infobox&quot;&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Informatie over pre-orders&lt;/h3&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Het is niet mogelijk om via onze webshop een pre-order te plaatsen.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Heb jij reeds een pre-order geplaatst op de PlayStation 5? Dan neemt de winkel waar jij dit deed &lt;strong&gt;vanaf 17 september zo spoedig mogelijk telefonisch contact met je op&lt;/strong&gt; om de status van je pre-order te bespreken. Wij nemen in &lt;strong&gt;chronologische volgorde&lt;/strong&gt; contact op met al onze PS5 pre-order klanten geplaatst tot en met 16 september 2020. Naargelang de datum waarop jij je pre-order plaatste kan het &lt;strong&gt;tot 10 dagen&lt;/strong&gt;&amp;nbsp;duren alvorens je winkel telefonisch contact met je opneemt.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Had jij v&amp;oacute;&amp;oacute;r 17 september 2020 nog geen pre-order geplaatst op de PlayStation 5? Ga dan langs in jouw Game Mania store om een pre-order te plaatsen en kom chronologisch op de PS5 wachtlijst te staan. Bij het plaatsen van een nieuwe pre-order is een aanbetaling van € 50 verplicht.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Welkom in een nieuwe wereld van realistisch gamen&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Ontdek een diepere game-ervaring op PS5&amp;trade; met ondersteuning voor haptische feedback, adaptieve triggers en 3D-audiotechnologie.&lt;br&gt;
    &lt;br&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;Voel meer met haptische feedback&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Geniet van haptische feedback via de draadloze DualSense&amp;trade;-controller in geselecteerde PS5-games en ervaar de effecten en impact van je acties in de game met je zintuigen.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Voel de weerstand met adaptieve triggers&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Maak gebruik van meeslepende adaptieve triggers met dynamische weerstandsniveaus die de fysieke impact van in-game activiteiten in geselecteerde PS5-games simuleren.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Kijk met geluid dankzij 3D-audio&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Duik in muzikale panorama&#39;s waar het voelt alsof het geluid uit elke richting komt. Met Tempest 3D AudioTech in ondersteunde games komt je omgeving echt tot leven via je hoofdtelefoon of de luidsprekers van je tv.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "Game Mania"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4",
        "ratingCount": "5187"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "499",
        "availability" : "OutOfStock"
    }
}'''

res_dict = json.loads(string.replace('\n',''))

print(res_dict['brand']['name'])
```

**Output**

```
Game Mania
```

Comment: but jsonformatter is giving an error when I past this in...will bs not give an error?

Comment: @NullumCC: Do you run my example code? It replace the linebreaks and then json works fine.

Comment: But it's data from a website, so it is monitoring it.

Comment: can't add my own json file because it wouldnt update.

Comment: Not sure, where is the problem to open your jupyter notbook or ide and run the example to see and learn what happens? Your question do not contain any code so how should I know what you are exactly doing - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks